# Factorise $f(x)=2x^3 -x^2-13x-6$ completely will give $(x-3)(2x+1)(x+2)$. Hence, how to solve $6y^3+13y^2+y-2=0$?

Tags: polynomials

Factorise $f(x)=2x^3 -x^2-13x-6$ completely will give $(x-3)(2x+1)(x+2)$.  Hence, how to solve $6y^3+13y^2+y-2=0$ ?

Comment: Where did $y$ come from? Please ensure you have added all details to the question. You are also more likely to get replies if you show that you have put some effort into solving the problem yourself first too

Comment: Divide the both sides of $f(x)=(x-3)(2x+1)(x+2)$ by $-x^3$.

Comment: The full question is "Factorise $f(x)=2x^3-x^2-13x-6$ completely.  Hence, solve the equation $6y^3+13y^2+y-2=0$.  I managed to do the 1st part, but is unable to link the answer to the 2nd part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the coefficients of the second polynomial are just the coefficients of the first polynomial in reverse order (with an irrelevant change of sign). So substituting  $y=1/x$ in the first polynomial gives you
$$\frac{2}{y^3}-\frac{1}{y^2}-\frac{13}{y}-6=0$$
Multiply this by $-y^3$ and you get the second polynomial. So the roots of the second polynomial are the reciprocals of the roots of the first polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

As before with $f(x)$, we can apply the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to obtain
$$
 6y^3+13y^2+y-2= (3y - 1)(2y + 1)(y + 2).
$$
This solves both cases and you don't need to derive one from the other (although that's easy as mathlove has commented).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the second equation is the transformation of the first equation when we replace x with $\frac{1}{y}$. So it the roots of the first eqn are  $\alpha \beta ,\gamma $then roots of the second eqn are $\frac{1}{\alpha}, \frac{1}{\beta},\frac{1}{\gamma}$

Comment: well, i mean if we change it from $\alpha$ to $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ we can transform the equation by replacing x with $\frac{1}{y}$

Comment: Well this is what I mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_transformation

Comment: Now i get your point. Yes, i never meant it was the only transformation. what i actually meant was the reciprocal equation. Though on the hindsight, i need to be more specific